# PHP Curl for Rest API not working

Tags: php, json, api, rest, curl

This works fine directly in bash:

```
curl https://test.url.com/api/id/98765 -H 'API_KEY: xxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=='
```

This does not work in PHP (nothing is returned):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'https://test.url.com/api/id/98765');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array(
                                            "API_KEY: xxxxxxxxxx8",
                                            "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
                                            ));         
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$results = curl_exec($curl);
echo 'out: '.$results;
```

No errors are returned. I'm expecting results in json

Comment: @user2029890 Is your error reporting is ON?

Comment: yes, error reporting is on. I tested by deliberately creating a syntax error

Comment: Blat! Nevermind, now I see that you have it working in CURL. \*Goes and digs deeper\*

Comment: Can you try adding `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`?

Comment: Is the request getting sent at all? If yes, what exactly is getting sent?

Comment: Are you using http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php to check for errors? Also, if you pull up the secure url in a browser, do you get a certificate error?

Comment: One difference I noticed from trying it out is that on the command line you get a user-agent in the request headers, but from PHP you don't (so you could try setting those).

Comment: @Remus. Perfect, the SSL line did it. Didn't think I would need it, but it did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazarding a guess (and we ultimately determined this to be true) that you need:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

(note that `0` is synonymous with `false`).

This stops the client from verifying the SSL certificate of the remote location. I suggested this because your url is on https:// but it looks like a custom built solution which you likely don't have a public trusted cert configured for it (yet).

More information on `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is available in [the php docs](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt).

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP code is working for me fine to a renowned API. Here i have to implement CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_USERAGENT. you can try with this

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://testurl.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```